# increment via trigger varchar value in the column

Tags: mysql, triggers

please help to solve one problem - I need to create after insert in table row with incremented value

| id | number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | inc1 |
| 2 | inc2 |

I need to insert inc3 in number column automatically. How to do that?

Comment: Remove this column and calculate needed value from your autoincremented `id` in the query with according expression or in a view.

Comment: how to calculate needed value from id? i need example

Comment: Possibly with [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)?

Comment: how i can get a previous id value from previous row to generate new number? because on insert when i use a concat ('inc', id) it insert 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Created a before insert trigger:

```
BEFORE INSERT ON `incident` FOR EACH ROW set NEW.`number` = CONCAT('INC' , (LPAD ((SELECT incident.sys_id from incident ORDER BY sys_id DESC LIMIT 1), 6, '0')))
```

this got a previous id and concat it